# Request module crashes in Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, request, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I try text_detection to photo. However, strange problem happens now.
I post very simply debug program.

the flow is:

1:defining variable(photo, google storage's path, vision's url)

2:generating the bearer token. Add it to ServiceToken.
(ref:https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth)

3: rbody is Google Cloud Vision's request.

4: Finally, using Request module. If Vision detects text, outputting json of the detected result(body:~~).

```
const request = require('request');

var filePath = "Photo01.jpg";
const imagePath = 'gs://***'+filePath;
const urlvision = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate';
var ServiceToken;
ServiceToken = "";

//OCR
let rbody = {
    requests: [{
        image: {
            source: {
                imageUri:imagePath
            }
        }, 
        features: [{type: 'TEXT_DETECTION'}]
    }]
};
let headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};

console.log(JSON.stringify(rbody));

request.post({
    url: urlvision,
    headers:headers,
    body:JSON.stringify(rbody)
},function(error,response,body){
    console.log("body:"+body);

    console.log("error:"+error);
}).auth(null,null,true,ServiceToken);
```

In my local pc, I confirmed that program works normally.Thus, I combined between firebase storage handler in cloud functions and this program. However, in Cloud functions, request module outputted this error.

```
error:TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
```

I can not understand this error. I think that this error indicates a header. But headers's variable is not modified. Why behavior of request module changes in cloud functions? Does anyone know the details?